# File Transfer from one SFTP location to another SFTP location using SSH.Net

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

We need to move the files from one SFTP Locaton to another SFTP location so is this possible using SSH.NET third party component.

Comment: Download the file, upload to second server, delete local copy, delete original copy

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I thought about this but there are no other ways to transfer the file directly from one SFTP location to another SFTP location?

Comment: As far as I know with ssh.net, there is no way to do what you ask as it doesn't support a server-to-server connection so far as I've ever seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that there are no *native* facilities in SSH.NET for connecting to two server simultaneously and having them communicate with each other. In order to do what you are asking the best course of action would be to:

1. Download the file from Server-1 to the local machine
2. Upload the file from local to Server-2
3. Delete file from Server-1
4. Delete file from local machine

Now that isn't to say it cannot be done. If your first remote server allows you to execute commands via SSH, and that server also has the necessary access to the second server (permissions, connectivity, private keys if applicable), you could in theory execute the raw commands to get the first server to connect to the second.

I am no SSH expert on what those commands would be. However, arbitrary commands *can* be executed for SSH by using the `SshClient` rather than the `SftpClient`. You could connect via SSH and then use `RunCommand`/`CreateCommand` on the `SshClient`. The following example creates a "tmp/uploadtest" directory on the server and gives it "rw" access. It then checks the status of the command afterwards.

```
using (var sshclient = new SshClient(...)){
            sshclient.Connect();
            using(var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand("mkdir -p /tmp/uploadtest && chmod +rw /tmp/uploadtest")){
                cmd.Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("Command>" + cmd.CommandText);
                Console.WriteLine("Return Value = {0}", cmd.ExitStatus);
            }
            sshclient.Disconnect();
}
```

(Code borrowed from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/piccaso/d963331dcbf20611b094))

You may be able to leverage this by calling `CreateCommand` with the appropriate arguments to initialize an ssh connection from Remote-1 to Remote-2 and then transferring the files that way.

Unless you are required to, I would opt for "the easy way"